# How to handle internal implementation of interfaces in a good way with getter only interfaces?

Tags: c#, interface

In a `contract` project I have defined some interface e.g.

```
public interface IProject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string Path { get; }
}
```

The interface is exposed to various front-ends (e.g WPF, command line etc.) by referencing the `contracts` assembly.
It is exposing only the getter of Path as no user should be able to modify if. Every modification happens in the `runtime` assembly.

The `runtime` project, which does all the heavy work implements am `internal` `Project` and of course needs some sort of setter for `Path` (property, ctor, etc.)

The `runtime` creates a `Project` but returns an `IProject` to the user to satisfy the contract.

When the user performs an action on the `IProject` e.g.

```
runtime.SetPath(iProjectObject, "my new path");
```

what is a proper way of obtaining a valid `Project` from the interfaced passed to `SetPath` ?

Is casting (and therefore [unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)) the way to go?
It somehow seems dirty to me to define nice contracts and then cast around.
However it is possible to assume that `IProject` will always be `Project` as it is created and managed by the `runtime` assembly only. But I cannot guarantee that a user does not derive from `IProject` and feed it into my `runtime`.

Non-casting alternatives like `runtime` having a map of `IProject` to `Project` references seems odd as they would basically point to the same object.

So every public `runtime` method dealing with `IProject` will need boilerplate for casting, assumptions, throwing on wrong type etc?

Comment: Why not simply provide the additional information needed in `IProject`, instead of trying to cast back to an underlying type?  Also, unless you're implementing the interface with a struct, and not a class, that's not unboxing, it's just casting.

Comment: @Servy, you are right concerning the unboxing. `IProject` itself has no logic as the `runtime` performs multithreading, dispatching, resource handling and sharing etc. in the background. Doing this in every `IProject` instance would be complex as there are plenty of `IProject` instances which would need synchronization. That would IMHO also break the single responsibility principle as `IProject` is basically just a result handle. While `runtime` is not monolithic in terms of doing everything, it still manages a common context for all `Projects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design perspective, if your consumer (runtime.SetPath) requires a Project instance and not simply the implementation of iProject then SetPath does not actually conform to the iProject interface contract to begin with, since it requires a cast to do anything useful with iProjectObject instead of treating it AS iProject.

This sounds instead like a good case for an abstract Project class that does the minimum Project relevant implementation necessary to satisfy the runtime while also allowing the user to subclass. This would eliminate that boilierplate unboxing / trycast stuff too.

Comment: Thank you for your input. You and @Servy pointed an important fact out.  I defined an interface and then started workarounds for it. From a design perspective there is no reason to create IProject as plain property container and provide another class for operations on them. The plain IProject object is basically an remnant from flow based design I experimented with, where "messages" flow between operations, and one of them was IProject. I'll redesign the entire thing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

use a mark interface, and makes it internal in your runtime assembly, and the let your service inherit form both the IProject and the mark interface. The when the runtime get the IProject instance, check if it is also type of the mark interface.

The code will like this in the runtime assembly :

```
internal interface IProjectTag{};
internal class ProjectService: IProject,IProjectTag{
public void SetPath
 {
    if (this is IProjectTag)
        {...}

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, while this would solve the problem at hand, it looks like a way to compensate a bad design decision I've made to treat IProject as plain data container. The other comments and answer made me to revise the concept to avoid such "context"-less objects.